# h264 clips from wmv's not working in HTML5 video on iPad (black screen)

Tags: ipad, html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I need to make .wmv files play in the video tag on iPad.  Using Handbrake I've gotten videos to play in Chrome, so I know my syntax is fine.  I've even got another website's mp4 to play on the iPad with no problems.

This is what ffmpeg says about my (not working) stream:

```
Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 320x238 [PAR 1:1 DAR 160:119], 32 kb/s, 28.77 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
```

This is what ffmpeg says about their (working) stream:

```
Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1280x544 [PAR 1:1 DAR 40:17], 1677 kb/s, 24.99 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

Here is my markup:
    html = '' +
              '' +
              '

video fail!

'
           ';
    $div.append(html);

I this that because the wmv's were first encoded in 2002 is causing the issue, but I have no way of being sure of that.
Here is what ffmpeg says about the wmv:

```
Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)
Input #0, asf, from 'pattySlotFormation.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 8.00.00.4477
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    artist          : Craig
    copyright       : 7/31/2002
  Duration: 00:00:13.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 691 kb/s
    Chapter #0.0: start 3.100000, end 13.779000
    Metadata:
      title           : Clip 73
    Stream #0.0: Audio: wmav2, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
    Stream #0.1: Video: wmv1, yuv420p, 320x240, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
```

Comment: Which version of iOS? Don't suppose you have the poster attribute set for your video in your markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out why this is happening, but I've found 2 solutions.

Upload the videos to youtube and embed them on your webpage.
Upload the videos to youtube and then download them as an mp4.  That file will work on iPad.